# Eclipse: App not installed! I guess error is in manifest file. Suggestions?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, installation

So I've made a test app. The main activity has a button. If you click that button, you go to another activity. 
But it just doesnt get installed on my phone. I've compiled with API 23 for my Kitkat device. I just cant build an app with two classes when I use intent.

Here is the main activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button b1;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.GOTHAM");
            startActivity(i);
            }
    });

  }


  }
```

The second activity:

```
 public class gotham extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gotham);

 }
 }
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hello"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".gotham"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GOTHAM" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>        
 </application>


 </manifest>
```

Comment: There are many reasons why an app may not have been installed. You need to post the specific error message. the code tells us almost nothing and it's worth reading through if we don't know what to look for.

Comment: Since months? Are you sure? :)

Comment: Please add the error you get after when you try to install the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should name your java classes beginning with an upper-case letter, like `Gotham` and not `gotham`.

Also in the manifest you can delete the intent filter as it is not needed at all, and you can create the intent in you `MainActivity` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Gotham.class);
```

After you've renamed your gotham activity to Gotham.

If these changes does not solve your problem, check the logcat output and also any error that eclipse produces when trying to build your app.